# Exchange Web Services - ServiceResponseException after sending Email message

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am using EWS Managed to send email.
Here is a code:

```
EmailMessage result = new EmailMessage( mService );
result.From = from;
result.Subject = subj;
result.Body = textBody;
if ( to != null )
{
    result.ToRecipients.AddRange( StringArrayToAddresses( to ) );
}
if ( cc != null )
{
   result.CcRecipients.AddRange( StringArrayToAddresses( cc ) );
}
if ( bcc != null )
{
   result.BccRecipients.AddRange( StringArrayToAddresses( bcc ) );
}
result.Send();
```

While running this on Exchange 2007 I am receiving [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.serviceresponseexception%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx):

> The request failed schema validation:
>   The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:EmailAddress'
>   element is invalid - The value '' is
>   invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:NonEmptyStringType'
>   - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.

While debugging, I have checked [From](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.email.emailmessage.from%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) and [ToRecepients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.torecipients%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) properties, both have [EmailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.emailaddress_members%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) assigned.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, its solved, my mistake!
Just have checked Bcc and Cc values. Found an empty string.